# How to limit RAM consumption in SQLAlchemy + Pandas operations?

Tags: python, pandas, memory, sqlalchemy

We have several processes that use SQLAlchemy to pull from a DB, and then Pandas to manipulate data. Do I `cast()` within my sql pull to a smaller datatype? Or do I load into into my dataframe as a smaller data type?

```
df = pd.read_sql("select cast(column_name as smallint) from schema.table;")
```

vs

```
df = pd.read_sql("select column_name from schema.table;", dtype={"column_name": "int8"})
```

Is there a way to change the default pandas numeric type. It seems to default to `int64`

Comment: How many rows are typically returned by the query? Do you need all, or a large fraction of those rows in the typical case? If not, have you considered trying to write a more specific query? Also, what is the data type actually stored in the database, according to the schema?

Comment: So we actually have many similar processes as parts of diff etl jobs. My goal is to put in place some better practices to limit our cloud costs. Most of the time we know exactly which columns a query asks for, but there's variance in row count/data size from day to day and from job to job.

Answer (score 0):

So after some looking around it seems that loading in a different default dtype isn't super feasible unless you want to specify each column individually, or want to cast() each column in your sql. Even then, it's another issue to make sure you're not going to lose any data. Overall I think this problem is fixed with more rigorous standards throughout all processes and not with a silver bullet (duh).

In the meantime, this will work to safely downcast columns post-load. The read functions still use most of the RAM, but for downstream operations this lessons space needed:

```
def downcast_integers(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """
    Args:
        df:
    Returns:
    """
    int_columns = df.select_dtypes(include=["int64"]).columns.tolist()
    df[int_columns] = df[int_columns].apply(pd.to_numeric, downcast='integer')
    return df
```

Float and object types can be done similarly.